# How do I update psql?

Tags: heroku, psql

I am migrating our database on heroku but am having troubles with one of the steps described here: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/migrating-from-shared-database-to-heroku-postgres

When I run "heroku pg:psql HEROKU_POSTGRESQL_ORANGE" in terminal, I get the following:

```
psql (9.0.4, server 9.1.4)
WARNING: psql version 9.0, server version 9.1.
     Some psql features might not work.
SSL connection (cipher: DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA, bits: 256)
Type "help" for help.

df638608u79sh=>
```

I've tried updating psql with "brew update postresql", "gem update psql" and so furth, but neither of them runs.

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not in the shell when you use `heroku pg:psql HEROKU_POSTGRESQL_ORANGE`, you are actually logged into a psql console instance. Postgres is already installed and configured for you

Comment: Shouldn't the output be like what Heroku write in their guide, then?
"Setting config variable DATABASE_URL to HEROKU_POSTGRESQL_COLOR_URL"

Comment: It seems to work even though I didn't get the output I expected, so closing the ticket. Thanks :)

Comment: It appears to use your local `psql` to effect the connection - your output is suggesting that you only have 9.0.4 locally. I would suggest looking at the output of `which psql` and then looking at the what the symlink is pointing at if you're using homebrew.